# Using Stash to store a variable in the loop based on a conditional

Tags: stash

I have this code.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    author_id="{segment_3}"
    channel="images"
    disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
    dynamic="no"
}
    {if no_results}
        {exp:stash:set name="default_image"}http://placehold.it/200x200/{/exp:stash:set}
    {/if}

    {if count == 1}
        {exp:stash:set name="default_image"}{image}{/exp:stash:set}
    {/if}

    {if is_default == 'yes'}
        {exp:stash:set name="default_image"}{image}{/exp:stash:set}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The goal of the logic here is to get default image. Here is the logic

1. If there are no results, use a default image
2. If there is only 1 profile image, use it as default image
3. If there is a default image set, use it as a default image

I try to use Stash to make this happen but outputting the contents of

```
{exp:stash:get name="default_image"}
```

returns a blank string.

Am I doing something wrong with Stash? Is it even possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to do and you're close, as most things it's a parse order issue, so some simple refactoring should suffice…

```
{exp:stash:set name="default_image" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
//Set stash here, so it parses conditionals
  {exp:channel:entries
    author_id="{segment_3}"
    channel="images"
    disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
    dynamic="no"
}
    {if no_results}http://placehold.it/200x200/{/if}
    {if count == 1}{image}{/if}//This could do with some thought - '1' & 'is_default' could be similar, if not the same and may cause issues.
    {if is_default == 'yes'}{image}{/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```